# Bundle React build results into single html file

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm using React and Webpack to create report page with test logs. I'm planning to distribute and store them offline and I'd prefer to have these reports each in a single html file. So I basically would like this html file to store inline js code. I can copy it manually after each release but is there any tool that can do it for me in a webpack? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you, with "html-webpack-plugin" you can generate an HTML file with a script tag to your index.js bundle. You can view documnetation [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin).

The code will be like this:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
...
...
plugins: [
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'app/index.html'
  })
],
```

Comment: Many thanks I will give it a try and see if it works!

Comment: Well, I'm struggling to get [this](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates) example to work. I can't see any errors in output but title of my page in browser is shown as `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>`. Maybe it's not working or server sending me unprocessed page. I'm not sure. Can you please elaborate more on your example?

Comment: First at all you need to install this plugin in your 'site' with npm. When you built your site with for example npm run create, an index.html file will be created at your built site.

htmlwebpack plugins allow you to create a copy of your index.html file for example and add some code, in my case the bundle of my js files...

Maybe first you need to read any webpack configuration. (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/)